# How to start Simple Table Server in Jmeter with nohup or get it to run in the background

Tags: linux, testing, jmeter, load, performance-testing

I have been trying to start the Simple Table Server for my testing with the following command: `./simple-table-server.sh > output.log 2>&1 & disown`

It doesn't work when I run the above command the Simple Table Server doesn't appear to be working.

I have got around this by manually creating a screen session, starting the simple table server and detaching but I am trying to automate the process now, so using I'm trying to figure out how to use nohup again.

Does anyone know how to run the Simple Table Server within Linux in the background?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start it from a shell script or shell you can use [nohup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) command, example:

```
nohup ./simple-table-server.sh >> simpletableserver.log 2>&1 &
```

Actually you can run it with JMeter by setting the following properties:

```
jmeterPlugin.sts.loadAndRunOnStartup=true
jmeterPlugin.sts.initFileAtStartup=your-file.csv
```

More information:

- [HTTP Simple Table Server](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HttpSimpleTableServer/) documentation
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization)